invalid access key for google apis
I would like to get the list of RSS feeds for YouTube channels to which I am subscribed.
I tried this way
$ curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?key=BLA...BLA...BLA...'
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_INVALID",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "youtube.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

As you can see there is some problem
API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.
Also if I connect to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?hl=it&project=yt-rss-342415&supportedpurview=project&pli=1
I see that the key is valid.

So what's the problem?
EDIT
Sorry, the API_KEYit was incorrect.
I fixed!
But it still doesn't work
# SYNTHESIS
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
        "errors": [   
            {
                  "message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
                  "domain": "global",
                  "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "API_KEY_HTTP_REFERRER_BLOCKED",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",  – 

Why?

A screenshot in English would help us to help you.

I fixed. refresh the page

Provide a screenshot in English of https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/youtube.googleapis.com

https://pasteboard.co/JXCClpu4ocbT.png

a screenshot in English (source)

https://pasteboard.co/9shUkYKmZYaK.png

Just click the ENABLE button on the screenshot you just sent, as detailed in this Stack Overflow answer.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I activated the youtube API https://pasteboard.co/FTnHTV6givqb.png (I don't know how to view the page in English).
However, it seems that something has changed now
`
$ curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?key=BLA...BLA...BLA...'
synthesis
"code": 403,
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "reason": "API_KEY_HTTP_REFERRER_BLOCKED",

`

@saven41 are you sure you copy/pasted the API_KEY correctly? - double check how you built the URL for the request. If you have a single letter wrong in the API_KEY, you'll get this error.

There are some updates.
Review the initial post last part

Nothing????????????????????
